# AWS CDK: How to find/fetch 'IntegrationId' of Integrations in API Gateway

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cdk

I'm not sure and struggling to fetch Integration property 'Integration ID' of HTTP API Gateway. Below is the code (in C#) to create an Integration, however, since 'Integration ID' is not available, I'm not able to attach it to the 'Route' using CDK.

```
var cfnIntegration = new CfnIntegration(this, "Intergration", new CfnIntegrationProps()
{
   ApiId = cfnAPI.AttrApiId,
   IntegrationType = "AWS_PROXY",
   IntegrationUri = "arn:aws:lambda:us-east-1:123456789:function:TestFunction",
   IntegrationMethod = "POST",
   PayloadFormatVersion = "2.0",
});
```

The above code creates Integration, successfully, but not yet attached to the Route, shown below:

```
CfnRoute cfnRoute = new CfnRoute(this, "Routes", new CfnRouteProps()
{
  ApiId = cfnAPI.AttrApiId,
  RouteKey = "POST /webhook/digitalChannel,
  Target = $"integrations/{integration_id}" // <--- This is where the problem is, can't attach the above created Integration since integration_id is not known
});
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```cs
Target = $"integrations/{cfnIntegration.Ref}"
```

A L1 construct's [Ref](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/dotnet/api/Amazon.CDK.CfnRefElement.html#Amazon_CDK_CfnRefElement_Ref) property will be rendered at synth-time as a CloudFormation `Ref` intrinsic function.  At deploy-time, as the `AWS::ApiGatewayV2::Integration` CloudFormation [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-apigatewayv2-integration.html#aws-resource-apigatewayv2-integration-return-values) say, *"Ref returns the Integration resource ID, such as abcd123"*.

Comment: Thank you fedonev as always, you've been my saviour. I had read about `Ref` and tried `cfnIntegration.Ref` and perhaps didn't get it correct due to some other issue. Nevertheless, its' working as expected.

Comment: @Aniruddha Glad to help.  FYI, the CDK has L2 constructs for `AWS::APIGatewayv2`.  They are in a separate  ["alpha"](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-apigatewayv2-alpha-readme.html) module, meaning breaking changes may still occur.

Comment: Yes, I did check that already. The document around it says `AWS::APIGatewayv2` is in experimental stage and features maybe rolled back. With that said, I chose not to proceed with it until it's stable.

Answer (score 1):

The integration ID is the [return value](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-apigatewayv2-integration.html#aws-resource-apigatewayv2-integration-return-values) from the CloudFormation resource.
You can use [CFN intrinsic functions](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/dotnet/api/Amazon.CDK.Fn.html) to reference it (or access the `Ref` member on the CDK resource).

Additionally, string interpolation is not useable in this case because the value is only resolved during deployment. You'll have to use the `Join` intrinsic  function to get around this.

I'm not all that familiar with C# but it should look something like the following:

```cs
CfnRoute cfnRoute = new CfnRoute(this, "Routes", new CfnRouteProps()
{
  ApiId = cfnAPI.AttrApiId,
  RouteKey = "POST /webhook/digitalChannel",
  Target = Fn.Join("/", {"integrations", cfnIntegration.Ref})
});
```

Comment: No.  The CDK _does handle_ intrinsic functions embedded in interpolated strings.  The CDK creates the `Join` for us.

Comment: @fedonev oh interesting. I have definitely run into issues with interpolation before and resorted to manually defining the string manipulation. I'd have to look into what interfered with this behavior in the first place.

Comment: Thank you Andrew for your valuable time and insight on the subject.